# Scheme Matrix-Operation Accumulate

Tags: matrix, vector, scheme, accumulate

I'm trying solve some exercises concerning matrix-operations in scheme. Therefore I have a procedure accumulate:

```
(define (accumulate operation startvalue sequence)
  (if (null? sequence)
      startvalue
      (operation (car sequence)
          (accumulate operation startvalue (cdr sequence)))))
```

For example:

```
(define (dot-product u v)
   (accumulate + 0 (map * u v)))
```

where Vectors (or matrices) are definded as lists (or lists of a lists), e.g.

```
(define v (list 1 2)) ;or
(define m (list (list 3 4) (list 5 6)))
```

Now have to realize the matrix-vector-product.
I should get something like this:

```
  (define (matrix-vector-product m v)
    (map + <?? v ??>  m)
```

Someone have a hint for me?

Peer

Update:
I've found a soloution calculating the matrix-vector-product. It doesn't really follows the pattern `(map <??> m)`, but at least it uses the procedures, which are already there.

```
(define (matrix-vector-product v m)
  (if (not (pair? m)) '()
      (cons (dot-product v (car m)) (matrix-vector-product v (cdr m)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a soloution elseware, but I don't really understand how it exactly works:

```
(define (matrix-vector-product m v)
  (map (lambda (row) (dot-product v row)) m))
```

As I see, the procedure, decribed by the lambda-expression, gets as argument the first argument of the higher procedure m.
Obviously not as the whole sequence, but the included pairs (the rows) one after the other. 
Why is that so?

Map needs as arguments a procedure and at least one list. 
Here the procedure is the lambda-expression, which is calculating the dot-product between the rows of m and v, and the list is m.
But the dot-product between the rows of m and v provides the soloution already, I don't see any mapping to the list m.

Maybe someone can solve my confusion.